# POST request error in Axios despite valid API route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios

For context, I am currently following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDV3Z1KCBvo&t=24294s) and I am on part 8 (payment processing). The payment processing is done using Stripe, Axios, and Node.js. For some reason, whenever I try to make a POST request to one of the API's routes, I receive a CORS error and Internal Server Error.

The payment page is set up as a component within React. When the user decides to proceed to checkout, the errors show up in the console:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-e99f7/us-central1/api/payments/create?total=2999' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Where the total is the cost of purchase multiplied by 100.

&

"POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-e99f7/us-central1/api/payments/create?total=2999 net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)"

A snippet of my code within the payment component is as follows:

```
    const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getClientSecret = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios({ // The error is likely here
                method: "post",
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
          } 
          catch (error) {
            console.log(error) // Error is never logged
          }
        };
      
        getClientSecret();
    }, [basket]);
```

Where the basket are the items the user is planning to purchase.

The code in my index.js file is as follows:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(/* secret key */);

// API

// - App config
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("This is working"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  console.log("Payment Request Received for this Amount: ", total);
  const total = request.query.total;

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntent.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: "usd",
  });

  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And finally, the code within my axios.js file is as follows:

```
import axios from "axios"

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-e99f7/us-central1/api" // API (cloud function) URL
})

export default instance;
```

The API URL works fine, but the second I attempt to make a POST request to /payments/create?total=x, the errors mentioned above are generated. The entire application is ran using the command `firebase emulators:start`

I've attempted using `cors({origin: "*"})` but that still did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a post request to the server, and you are not specifying the data to post, even if it is going to be empty you can just specify:

```
const response = await axios({ 
   method: "post",
   url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
   data: {}
});
```

Comment: you could also add headers to the request 
`headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },`